# Is it possible to GROUP BY an aggregate query with django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to calculate the equivalent of `SELECT SUM(...) FROM ... GROUP BY ...`. Here's a simplified analogy:

Let's say `Salesperson` objects sell stuff and get a commission on the margin they generate through each `Sale`:

```
sp = Salesperson.objects.get(pk=1)
my_sales = Sale.objects.filter(fk_salesperson=sp)

#calculate commission owing to sp
commission = 0
for sale in my_sales:
    commission += sp.commission_rate\
                     * (sale.selling_price - sale.cost_price)
```

That last loop could be done with something like:

```
.annotate( commission= ( F('selling_price')-F('cost_price') )\
                            * sp.commission_rate )
```

But can I then further aggregate the query for all `Salesperson` objects? I.e. I want to know *every* salesperson's commission (i.e. roughly `SELECT SUM( (sale_price-cost_price) * commission_rate) FROM Sales GROUP BY Salesperson`). I could do something like below, but I'm trying to do it with ORM:

```
commissions = []
salespeople = Salesperson.objects.all()
for sp in salespeople:
    data = Sale.objects.filter(fk_salesperson=sp)\
       .annotate(salesperson=F('sp__email')\
       .annotate(commission= ( F('selling_price')-F('cost_price') )\
                                 * sp.commission_rate )
    commissions.append(data)
```

Is there a way to do this with a single query (making the reporting db server do the work) rather than doing it on my application server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sum()` aggregate function is available in `django.db.models` and you can use related fields in an F expression.

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Sales.objects.values('salesperson__id').annotate(commission=Sum(
    (F('selling_price') - F('cost_price')) * F('salesperson__commission_rate')
))
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortuneately your solution doesn't understand the essence of the question.The example is deliberately constructed so that there is no related field '`sales`' in the `Salesperson` model. (This is logical: a sale should be a foreign key pointing to a salesperson, not the other way around). The purpose of the example is to find a solution to query on `Sale` and then group on the related field foreign key to `Sale` called "`fk_salesperson`".

Comment: There **is** a relation, though implicit. It is a reverse relation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: I'd recommend to set [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) attribute for each ForeignKey to give it a meaningful name. If you did not set one, I think it should be `sale_set__` instead of `sales__`.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good logical translation of the simple SQL query though (`SELECT SUM( (sale_price-cost_price) * commission_rate) FROM Sales GROUP BY Salesperson`). Is there a more pythonic way that better mirrors the simplicity of the raw SQL?

Comment: You are right, I fixed my solution, starting from Sales rather than Salesperson.

Comment: Merci bien mon ami